# Fijar cabecera de tabla que crece dinámicamente

Tags: php, html, css, html-tabla, tabla-dinámica

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

La filas se desplegan o se ocultan haciendo uso de los iconos de la primera columna (marcados en verde) Necesito fijar tanto esa primera columna (Tiendas) como la cabecera de la tabla.

[image: bien]

Buscando encontré un código de boostrap que me funcionó al primer intento,

https://codepen.io/yavuzselim/pen/LNYrBd

Luego ya no funcionó, el navegador ni siquiera lee la clase .table-fixed, en un segundo intento me arroja de error que el estilo estaba mal formado o algo así, ahora no lo "ve".

```css
.table-fixed{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  tbody{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
  thead,tbody,tr,td,th{
    display:block;
  }
  tbody{
    td{
      float:left;
    }
  }
  thead {
    tr{
      th{
        float:left;
       background-color: #f39c12;
       border-color:#e67e22;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Lo modifiqué por:

```css
.table-fixed{
    width: 100% !important;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.table-fixed thead,
.table-fixed tbody,
.table-fixed tr,
.table-fixed td,
.table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}

.table-fixed tbody td{
   float:left;
}
```

Y fue peor porque la tabla se deforma toda y me da lo que se ve en ésta segunda imagen.

Alguien puede ayudarme.

[image: tabla mal formada]

Encontré éste código que me funciona para fijar la cabecera:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc() {
document.getElementById('table-scroll').onscroll = function() {

document.getElementById('fixedY').style.top = document.getElementById('table-scroll').scrollTop + 'px';
document.getElementById('fixedX').style.left = document.getElementById('table-scroll').scrollLeft + 'px';

};
 document.getElementById('corner').style.width = document.getElementById('fixedX').offsetWidth -4 + "px";
}

window.onload = fnc;
</script>
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
#table-scroll {
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
overflow: auto;
}

table, td, th {
border: rgba(193, 193, 193, 0.48) 1px solid;
}


#fixedY{
position: relative;
top: 0;
z-index: 99;
background-color: red;
}


#fixedY table{
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 900px;
}


#fixedY table th, #fixedY table td {
width: 25%;
}


#fixedY table th {
background-color: red;
font: bold 15px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}


#cuerpoDatos {
width: 900px;
overflow: hidden; 
}

#cuerpoDatos > div{
float: left;
}


#cuerpoDatos > div#fixedX{
width: 25%;
position: relative;
left: 0;
z-index: 98;
background-color: yellow;
}

#cuerpoDatos > div#fixedX table{
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}


#cuerpoDatos > div#nofixedX{
width: 75%;
}

#cuerpoDatos > div#nofixedX table{
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

#cuerpoDatos > div#nofixedX table td {
width: 33%;
}

 #corner{
 font: bold 15px/120% Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 text-align: center; 
 border: orange 2px solid;
 background-color: orange; 
 position: fixed; 
 top: default; 
 margin-top: -1.5em; 
 z-index: 2147483647; 
 }

</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>


</head>
<body>

<div id="table-scroll">

<div id="fixedY">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Lote</th><th>Producto 1</th><th>Producto 2</th><th>Producto 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>

<div id="cuerpoDatos">
 <div id="corner"> ☺ </div>

<div id="fixedX">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Viaje 9</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div id="nofixedX">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>moto</td><td>avión</td><td>barco</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Pero no me funciona para fijar la fila, cómo hacer qué

```
#cuerpoDatos > div#fixedX{
width: 25%;
position: relative;
left: 0;
z-index: 98;
background-color: yellow;
}

#cuerpoDatos > div#fixedX table{
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
```

sea aplicable a un td dentro de la tabla, ya que no me funciona como está porque la tabla crece dinámicamente.

Answer (score 1):

el problema capaz es que tengas la extencion del estilo `.css` mientras el codigo de codepen es `.scss`. para que funcion en css tendria que quedar asi:

```css
body{
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
.table-fixed{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.table-fixed tbody{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed tbody td{
   /* float: left;*/
}
.table-fixed thead tr th{
   /*float: left;*/
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-color:#e67e22;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-3">First Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Last Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

si queres el `float: left;` podes meterlo, a mi me gustaba mas sin por eso lo comente.

espero que te sea de ayuda. exitos